# Validate Multiple Input fields using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to do the validations for multiple input fields by using JavaScript and jQuery. I am getting validations for individual fields, but the page is loading when i click submit button, so the filled data is gone.

My Code is:
HTML:

```
<form id="addadmin-form" name="addadmin-form" onsubmit="return addAdminValidation123();" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="controls">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text"/>
    <div id="name-error" class="validationerror">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <input name="qualification" id="qualification" type="text"/>
    <div id="qualification-error" class="validationerror">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <input name="desc" id="desc" type="text"/>
    <div id="desc-error" class="validationerror">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addAdminValidation123(){
  $('#addadmin-form').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    if($(this).val()=="") {
      document.getElementById(""+id+"-error").innerHTML="PLEASE FILL OUT THIS FIELD !";    
      $('#'+id+'-error').css('display','block');
      return divTagDisplayHide(5000);
    }
  });
}

function divTagDisplayHide(time){
  $(".validationerror" ).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {            
      $this.hide();
    }, time);
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `.preventDefault()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add the below jQuery code after your js functions.
- And remove `onsubmit` handler from form tag

Here `event.preventDefault();` will prevent form to submit and page loading.

```js
// YOUR JS FUNCTIONS HERE 

$(document).on('submit', '#addadmin-form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    addAdminValidation123();
});
// Still error occurs you can always debug through Firebug Console.
```

Comment: Welcome :) 
You can mark question as solved if it does.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something along these lines. Check to see if each field is empty and if one is `preventDefault` to stop the form from submitting and show the error message

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){

  if($("#name").val() == ""){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#name-error").text("Cant be empty")    
  }else{
    $("#name-error").text("")
  }

  if($("#qualification").val() == ""){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#qualification-error").text("Cant be empty")    
  }else{
    $("#qualification-error").text("")
  }

  if($("#desc").val() == ""){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#desc-error").text("Cant be empty")    
  }else{
    $("#desc-error").text("")
  }

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/poo03yg8/)

Answer (score 0):

Your addAdminValidation123 function is not returning any value.  This is why the page is allowing you to submit the form.  When you are executing "return divTagDisplayHide(5000);" this is returning false for the inner function - the one that starts from "$('#addadminform').find('input[type="text"]').each(**function()**{"

Try the following to fix the problem.

`function addAdminValidation123(){
    var returnVal = true;
    $('#addadmin-form').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        if($(this).val()=="")
        {
            document.getElementById(""+id+"-error").innerHTML="PLEASE FILL OUT THIS FIELD !";

            $('#'+id+'-error').css('display','block');
            returnVal =  divTagDisplayHide(5000);
        }
    });
    return returnVal;
}`